# PM2 not showing python application version

Tags: python, version, pm2

I have a python app running under pm2. When I execute `pm2 ls`, the column showing app versions says N/A for the that script.

For NodeJS, I solved the issue setting in the ecosystem file the field `cwd` to the folder containing the `package.json`. But pointing `cwd` to the folder containing `__init__.py` does not work.

Is there a way to let pm2 extract version for python applications?

Comment: Is there any version in your __init__.py?

Comment: yes, inside my `__init__.py` I have set a variable called `__version__`

Comment: For now PM2 only implements version parsing of package.json, you can add a package.json in your python app or do a pull request around this line to support `__init__.py` file parsing https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/38ea71ee3a2b268bf6b3e915ce36cc2b9e93051d/lib/Utility.js#L18